# Inserting data to database in the onClick method

Tags: java, android, sqlite

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements SensorEventListener, OnClickListener {

    private SensorManager mSensorManager;
    private Sensor mAcc;
    TextView xaxis,yaxis,zaxis,ballxy,gps,statics;
    public float velocity = 10.6f;
    public float xPosition,yPosition,zPosition;
    public static float staticXposition,staticYposition,staticZposition;
    private Database myDBAdapter;

    public ContentValues values;

    public String GPSposition;
    public SQLiteDatabase db;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mSensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
        mAcc = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);

        LocationManager locMgr = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        LocationListener locList = new LocationListener() {

            @Override
            public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                gps.setText("GPS:"+location.getLatitude()+";"+location.getLongitude());
                GPSposition = location.getLatitude() + " " + location.getLongitude();

            }
        };
        locMgr.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locList);


        // inicjowanie TextView
        gps = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.gps);
        xaxis = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.xaxis);
        yaxis = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.yaxis);
        zaxis = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.zaxis);
        ballxy = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ballxy);
        statics = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.statics);



        Button start = (Button) findViewById(R.id.start);
        start.setOnClickListener(this);


        myDBAdapter = new Database(this).open();
        //TODO Any database operations
        myDBAdapter.close();


    }


    public void insertData(){


        String time;
        Time now = new Time();
        now.setToNow();
        time = now.toString();

        values.put("ID", "1");
        values.put("LEFT_POSITION", xPosition);
        values.put("RIGHT_POSITION", yPosition);
        values.put("GPS", GPSposition);
        values.put("TIME", time);

        if(db!=null){
            db.insert("baza", null, values);    
        }else{
            Log.d("AppName","db is null");
        }



    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public final void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
        ImageView ball = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ball);
        xPosition = event.values[0] - staticXposition;
        yPosition = event.values[1] - staticYposition;
        zPosition = event.values[2] - staticZposition;

    }




    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPause();
        mSensorManager.unregisterListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onResume();
        mSensorManager.registerListener(this, mAcc, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
    }




    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        switch(v.getId()){
        case R.id.start:

            staticXposition = xPosition;
            staticYposition = yPosition;
            staticZposition = zPosition;

            insertData();


        }

    }


}
```

I created method with contentValues:

```
public void insertData(){


        String time;
        Time now = new Time();
        now.setToNow();
        time = now.toString();

        values.put("ID", "2");
        values.put("LEFT_POSITION", xPosition);
        values.put("RIGHT_POSITION", xPosition);
        values.put("GPS", GPSposition);
        values.put("TIME", time);

        db.insert("baza", null, values);


    }
```

And I'm trying to send data into database "baza", when user will push the button.

```
public void onClick(View v) {

        switch(v.getId()){
        case R.id.start:

            staticXposition = xPosition;
            staticYposition = yPosition;
            staticZposition = zPosition;
                insertData();


        }

    }
```

I have some variables: xPosition, yPosition and zPosition. Data in this variables are dynamic, dependent on accelelometer. I'm trying to send this data to my database, but I have a error: Fatal exception main. Null pointer exception. Where I have a mistake?

```
01-12 12:42:17.093: E/AndroidRuntime(9216): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-12 12:42:17.093: E/AndroidRuntime(9216): java.lang.NullPointerException
01-12 12:42:17.093: E/AndroidRuntime(9216):     at pl.pawelfrydrych.flyingball.MainActivity.insertData(MainActivity.java:123)
01-12 12:42:17.093: E/AndroidRuntime(9216):     at pl.pawelfrydrych.flyingball.MainActivity.onClick(MainActivity.java:218)
01-12 12:42:17.093: E/AndroidRuntime(9216):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4240)
01-12 12:42:17.093: E/AndroidRuntime(9216):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17721)
01-12 12:42:17.093: E/AndroidRuntime(9216):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
01-12 12:42:17.093: E/AndroidRuntime(9216):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
01-12 12:42:17.093: E/AndroidRuntime(9216):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-12 12:42:17.093: E/AndroidRuntime(9216):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
01-12 12:42:17.093: E/AndroidRuntime(9216):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-12 12:42:17.093: E/AndroidRuntime(9216):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
01-12 12:42:17.093: E/AndroidRuntime(9216):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
01-12 12:42:17.093: E/AndroidRuntime(9216):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
01-12 12:42:17.093: E/AndroidRuntime(9216):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-12 12:42:19.673: I/Process(9216): Sending signal. PID: 9216 SIG: 9
```

Comment: post your error log !

Comment: Which row is MainActivity.java:123?

Comment: MainActivity.java:123 is: empty space in method insertData before values.put("ID","2");
I think that problem is in ContentValue. It look like good, so I don't have any idea why it not work :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your db
Try this code:

```
public void insertData(){


        String time;
        Time now = new Time();
        now.setToNow();
        time = now.toString();

        values.put("ID", "2");
        values.put("LEFT_POSITION", xPosition);
        values.put("RIGHT_POSITION", xPosition);
        values.put("GPS", GPSposition);
        values.put("TIME", time);

        if(db!=null)        
            db.insert("baza", null, values);
        else
            Log.d("AppName","db is null);
}
```

Edited Answer:

```
myDBAdapter = new Database(this).open();
        //TODO Any database operations
        myDBAdapter.close();
```

Why are you closing your database adapter here? After inserting the values this should be closed.Plus where are you initialising db?

Edit no. 2:
Change this in your code

```
protected void onStop() {
     myDBAdapter.close();;
 }
```

The visible lifetime of an activity happens between a call to onStart() until a corresponding call to onStop(). During this time the user can see the activity on-screen, though it may not be in the foreground and interacting with the user. Between these two methods you can maintain resources that are needed to show the activity to the user. For example, you can register a BroadcastReceiver in onStart() to monitor for changes that impact your UI, and unregister it in onStop() when the user no longer sees what you are displaying. The onStart() and onStop() methods can be called multiple times, as the activity becomes visible and hidden to the user.

Please go through the basic of android.

Comment: Unfortunately, db is not null :P

Comment: Have you opened your database in write mode? Are you writing on external storage? Please paste your code.

Comment: It's too much rows.. but OK. Database was created, it isn't problem. Problem is when I try to put data here :(

Comment: First learn how use database in android Marakana videos are best to learn  .Please search for database maRakana youtube

Comment: Don't close your database in onCreate(). Remove myDBAdapter.close(); and paste it in onStop().

Comment: I don't have onStop() method. You mean 
myDBAdapter = new Database(this).open();
myDBAdapter.onStop(); ?
Application crashed :(